# Slow Query Problem in MongodB Indexed query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

when I try to pull a data with approximately 30-50 MB in Mongodb, although it is index, Mongodb closes itself. found this error in logs;

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-22T09:30:02.497+01:00"},
"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn11","msg":"Slow query",
"attr":{"type":"command","ns":"mongodb-db.collection","appName":"MongoDB Compass",
"command":{"explain":{
"find":"collection",
"filter":{"site":"somesite.com"},"sort":{"_id":1},"skip":9000,"limit":3000,"maxTimeMS":60000},
"verbosity":"allPlansExecution","lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"a157f3e5-19f9-4d60-a569-2676bdad05e6"}},
"$db":"mongodb-db"},"numYields":3093,"reslen":11076,"locks":{"FeatureCompatibilityVersion":{"acquireCount":{"r":3094}},"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":3094}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":3094}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":3094}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":3094}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"storage":{"data":{"bytesRead":3107404391,"timeReadingMicros":30193302}},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":58737}}
```

Server Feature;
4Cpu 8Ram

Comment: The information message (`"s":"I"`) shows that it is reading over 3.1 GB from disk and takes over 30 seconds.  You have an index on `"site"`?

Comment: +1, as usual, to what @rickhg12hs said. Further - this is an explain from Compass, can you provide the full raw (text) output to your question? Finally, it looks like you may be attempting pagination here as there is also a `sort`, `skip`, and `limit`. A compound index would help here, but a range-based approach to the pagination would be even better.